# How to stop messages from appearing as system messages

Tags: android

I use gionee m6 lite phone and suddenly some messages appear as system messages and requires me to put in password before I can read the messages. How do I change it to normal messages that are visible in inbox

Comment: the system messages must be appearing in notification bar which are information about the android system. you can't change it to appear in the inbox.

Comment: @ashish. This are messages from my contacts.